# Using Testing Class to see if two integer values fit arguments

Tags: java

If the two values are set to a value between 0 and 29, if the the number provided in the argument is the sum of these two numbers, and the argument number and instance number are the same.

here is the code that I have written so far:

```
public class TwoNumbers {
      private int firstnum = 0;
      private int secondnum = 0;

//Constructor that initialize the first and second number
//to a value of 0

    public TwoNumbers()
    {
            firstnum = 0;
            secondnum = 0;
    }

    public int getFirstNum(){
            return firstnum;
    }
    public int getSecondNum(){
            return secondnum;
    }


    public boolean setFirstNum (int firstnum){
            if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29){
                    return true;
            }
            else {
                    return false;
            }
    }
    public boolean setSecondNum (int secondnum)
    {

            if (secondnum >= 0 && secondnum <=29){
                    return true;
            }
            else {
                    return false;
            }
    }
    public boolean checkSum (int sum){
            if (sum == firstnum + secondnum){
                    return true;
            }
            else {
                    return false;
            }

    }
    public boolean equals (int numbers1) {
            if (firstnum == secondnum){
                    return true;
            }
            else{
                    return false;
            }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setters aren't setting the new values.

```
public boolean setFirstNum (int newValue){
            firstnum = newValue;
            if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29){

                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
public boolean setSecondNum (int newValue)
{
        secondnum = newValue;
        if (secondnum >= 0 && secondnum <=29){
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
```

and tests 14 and 15 are not checking the value of the numbers.
`return numbers1.equals(numbers2);` should instead read
`return numbers1.firstNumber == numbers2.firstNumber && numbers1.secondNumber == numbers2.secondNumber;`

Comment: should I set them like this `firstnum = 0` and `secondnum = 0`

Comment: I recommend changing your argument names to help make your code more legible ie: public boolean setFirstNum(int newValue)

Comment: No, you need to set them to the values you're passing in the setFirstNum and setSecondNum methods.

Comment: I should also note that setters don't typically have return values, they're usually void, I encourage you to follow this as a standard practice to make your code more readable to others.

Comment: but the method is boolean type, it needs return value? for true and false

Comment: @GlenPierce is right . you have to set first the value in class TwoNumbers then compare and return result. your code will still return true but the value of firstNum in TwoNumbers class is still zero

Comment: I do set it to zero in class TwoNumebrs

Comment: @GlenPierce There is a logical mistake in your answer. If the value is between or equals 0 and 29, then you should set the value and return true, otherwise you shouldn't set anything, which means the value will remain 0 and return false.

Comment: @Rosifr, the method signature would be: public void setFirstNum(int newValue) instead of public boolean setFirstNum(int newValue)

Comment: @Kaan, I'm not certain that the desired behavior is to set the value only if the new value is between 0 and 29, but if that were, then I would simply move firstnum = newValue; into the body of the if statement just above return true;

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the values which you have set.

```
public static boolean test15() {
        TwoNumbers numbers1 = new TwoNumbers();
        numbers1.setFirstNum(1);
        numbers1.setSecondNum(4);

        TwoNumbers numbers2 = new TwoNumbers();
        numbers2.setFirstNum(4);
        numbers2.setSecondNum(1);

        return numbers1.equals(numbers2);
}
```

In the case number 15, you are checking that is **1** equal to **4**. Therefore, it returns `false` and there is nothing wrong with this test case.

Change it with:

```
numbers2.setFirstNum(1);
numbers2.setSecondNum(4);
```

In the case number 2, you haven't set the `secondNum` but you are trying to check it that's why it returns `false`.

```
public static boolean test2() {
        TwoNumbers numbers = new TwoNumbers();
        boolean success = numbers.setFirstNum(1);
        return success && (numbers.getFirstNum() == 1) && (numbers.getSecondNum() == 0);
}
```

Add the line below:

```
boolean success = numbers.setSecondNum(0);
```

In the case number 6, you haven't set the `firstNum` but you are trying to check it that's why it returns `false` as well.

```
public static boolean test6() {
        TwoNumbers numbers = new TwoNumbers();
        boolean success = numbers.setSecondNum(1);
        return success && (numbers.getFirstNum() == 0) && (numbers.getSecondNum() == 1);
}
```

Add the line below:

```
boolean success = numbers.setFirstNum(0);
```

I have realised your mistake, when I looked the case number 14.. Your setter methods don't set the values. They just return false or true. Please update them as below:

```
public boolean setFirstNum (int firstnum) {
    if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29) {
            this.firstnum = firstnum;
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}

public boolean setSecondNum (int secondnum) {
    if (secondnum >= 0 && secondnum <=29) {
            this.secondnum = secondnum;
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but it should still pass because it will check to see that 1 does not equal 4

Comment: No unfortunately, you are wrong. Since the result is false, then it prints "failed.".

Comment: so ive updated the setSecondNum like this: ` public boolean setFirstNum (int firstnum){
  secondnum = 0;
  if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29){
   return true;
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
 }` but still failing second test

Comment: add boolean success = numbers.setSecondNum(0); to the setSecondNum method?

Comment: Could you please check again my final answer

Comment: those methods dont return type boolean

Comment: The Setter and Getter methods are not used to returning something boolean unless the variables are boolean. Please check this website: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: By the way, I didn't see that you are keeping the result in a boolean variable "success" that's why I have removed the return true line. Now, I have updated and I am sure all the tests will be successful.

Comment: all but 14 and 15. I think perhaps I have wrong method for checksum and equals

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer, you should set the firstNum and secondNum for the test case 2 and 6. Because there is no connection between these methods and checksum.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestion for you:

- You should use JUnit rather than building your own testing mechanism. Rather than returning boolean values and printing error messages you could have very clear test statements like `assertEquals("default num1 is zero", 0, new TwoNumbers().getFirstNum())`
- Keep your getters and setters clean: getters should just return the value and setters should just set the value.
- If there's an error condition such as the argument being outside an expected range then throw and exception rather than returning a boolean.
- Have unit tests confirming that the correct exceptions are thrown under the right conditions (using JUnit's `expected` annotation key).

If you start with those changes I suspect your issues will become pretty obvious pretty quickly and you'll be learning better practices from the start.

Answer (score 0):

as commented by @GlenPierce but with some changes

```
public boolean setFirstNum (int firstnum){
        if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29){
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
public boolean setSecondNum (int secondnum)
{

        if (secondnum >= 0 && secondnum <=29){
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
```

should be

```
public boolean setFirstNum (int firstnum)
{

        if (firstnum >= 0 && firstnum <=29){
        this.firstnum = firstnum; //this is to set the value for TwoNumbers class in your object
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
public boolean setSecondNum (int secondnum)
{

        if (secondnum >= 0 && secondnum <=29){
        this.secondnum = secondnum; //this is to set the value for TwoNumbers class in your object
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }
}
```

and this will work fine now.

even though you get true or false from TwoNumbers class. There value will always be zero with your instance without setting them in setFirstNum and setSecondNum.

use the **this** keyword to set them. This is just one of the solution, there are still other ways like what @GlenPierce did.

**for 14 and 15**

```
// testing equals()
public static boolean test14() {
    TwoNumbers numbers1 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers1.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers1.setSecondNum(4);

    TwoNumbers numbers2 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers2.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers2.setSecondNum(4);

    return numbers1.equals(numbers2);
}

public static boolean test15() {
    TwoNumbers numbers1 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers1.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers1.setSecondNum(4);

    TwoNumbers numbers2 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers2.setFirstNum(4);
    numbers2.setSecondNum(1);

    return numbers1.equals(numbers2);
}
```

this will fail because your logic is wrong. in **.equal** method of your TwoNumbers accepts int while you are passing the whole object.

change **14** and **15** and **equal method** to this and everything will be fine

```
// testing equals()
public static boolean test14() {
    TwoNumbers numbers1 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers1.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers1.setSecondNum(4);

    TwoNumbers numbers2 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers2.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers2.setSecondNum(4);

    return numbers1.equals(numbers2.secondnum);
}

public static boolean test15() {
    TwoNumbers numbers1 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers1.setFirstNum(1);
    numbers1.setSecondNum(4);

    TwoNumbers numbers2 = new TwoNumbers();
    numbers2.setFirstNum(4);
    numbers2.setSecondNum(1);

    return numbers1.equals(numbers2.secondnum);
}

public boolean equals (int numberYouPassed) {

        //firstnum is the value from your numbers1
        //numberYouPassed is the value from numbers2.secondnum that you passed

        if (firstnum == numberYouPassed){  
                return true;
        }
        else{
                return false;
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: this only helped pass test 2. Now test 8 fails using this.

Comment: i'm still trying to see your code. atleast we answered one of your problem :) let's do it one by one . hehe . just wait and i'll update mmy answer

Comment: no problem. I think maybe using `this` will help with this solution, no?

Comment: do you think changing it to firstnum < 0 && firstnum > 29 and return true and else as false would work?

Comment: no. you're code logic is right. don't change it to  firstnum < 0 && firstnum > 29 because it will return false. I already changed my answer. I forgot to put i t inside to if. it will now work properly for 8 :)

Comment: just put the this.firstnum and this.secondnum inside the if so that it will only be set if it is greater than or equal 0 and less than or equal to 29

Comment: it  will really fail because your code for it is wrong. I'll update my answer, just wait

Comment: actually you can pass the object with parameter of (TwoNumbers numbers2) and use it  on equal method . I just used the int for easy digestion